# Apply checkbox for two tables in jsp using <display:table>

Tags: jquery, jsp, checkbox, struts2, displaytag

In the jsp, I have two tables for two different type of users (administrator and secretary) to view. Those tables has checkbox for download multiple files.

I have a strange (I think) situation which is only one type of user (administrator) can check all checkboxes by click the checkbox near the first table column.

I would like to show you the code about those table first.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#clickAll").click(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
       {
         $("input[name='chkdownload']").each(function() {
             $(this).attr("checked",true);
         });
       }
       else
       {
         $("input[name='chkdownload']").each(function() {
             $(this).attr("checked",false);
         });           
       }
    });
});
var countChecked = function() {
    var n = $( "input:checked" ).length; 
    if (n == 0) { 
        alert("Please click at least one record.");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }

}; 
</script>

<div class="content">
<s:form namespace="/DownloadFile" action="download_getSelectedFile" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<!--for administrator users to view -->
<div class="usrAdmin usrAccess" style="display:none">
<display:table name="${equipmentList}" class="its" uid="row"
    sort="list" pagesize="10" requestURI="equipment_view" export="false" defaultsort="1" defaultorder="descending">
  <display:columntitle="<input type='checkbox' name='selectall' id='clickAll'/>"><s:checkbox theme="simple" name="chkdownload" fieldValue='%{#attr.row.recordId}' /></display:column>
  <display:column property="equipName" title="Equipment Name" />
  <display:column property="equipLocation" title="Equipment Location" />
  <display:column property="equipOfficer" title="Equipment Officer" />
  </display:table>
</div>

   <!--for secretary users to view -->
   <div class="usrSec usrAccess" style="display:none">
<!-- put row2 to make the table uid unique -->
<display:table name="${equipmentList}" class="its" uid="row2"
    sort="list" pagesize="10" requestURI="equipment_view" export="false" defaultsort="1" defaultorder="descending">
  <display:column title="<input type='checkbox' name='selectall' id='clickAll'/>"><s:checkbox theme="simple" name="chkdownload" fieldValue='%{#attr.row.recordId}' /></display:column>
  <display:column property="equipName" title="Equipment Name" />
  <display:column property="equipLocation" title="Equipment Location" />
  <display:column property="equipOfficer" title="Equipment Officer" />
</display:table>
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Download Selected"/>
</s:form>
</div>
```

When I run the program, if I switch to secretary mode, I click the checkbox near the header column, it does not checked all checkboxes. It just shows a "tick" symbol in the checkbox only. However if I switch to administrator mode, I click the checkbox, it can checked all checkboxes.

At the beginning, I think maybe I mistype the incorrect name in jquery, but I review the code, both table are call the same input "chkdownload".

I have read the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/setting-checked-for-a-checkbox-with-jquery) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/how-to-check-whether-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-jquery) post, but I think my case is different to them.

Which part I did wrong in the code? It seems no typo error there. Otherwise, the checkbox in administrator mode will not work too.

Would someone let me know my mistake, please?

**Update**

I follow the instruction suggest by @reporter. I copy the html source code from Internet Explorer (IE). I see more code are generated and I would like to show it below for your review please. Thank you.

```
<div class="content">

<form id="download_getSelectedFile" name="download_getSelectedFile" onsubmit="return(countChecked());beginDownload();" action="/RIDW/Download/download_getSelectedFile.action" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<!--for administrator users to view -->
<div class="usrAdmin usrAccess" style="display:none;">
<span class="pagebanner">2 records  found, displaying all pages.</span> 
<span class="pagelinks">Page 1</span>
<table id="row" class="its">
<thead>
<tr>
<th><input type='checkbox' name='selectall' id='clickAll'/></th>
<th class="sortable">
<a href="equipment_view?d-16544-s=1&amp;d-16544-o=2&amp;d-16544-p=1">Equipment Name</a></th>
<th class="sortable">
<a href="equipment_view?d-16544-s=2&amp;d-16544-o=2&amp;d-16544-
p=1">Location</a></th>
<th class="sortable sorted order2">
<a href="equipment_view?d-16544-s=3&amp;d-16544-o=2&amp;d-16544-
p=1">Equipment Officer</a></th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="odd">
<td><input type="checkbox" name="chkdownload" value="427b0a45dd714d95bd11374b5a2d56b4" id="download_getSelectedFile_chkdownload"/><input type="hidden" id="__checkbox_download_getSelectedFile_chkdownload" name="__checkbox_chkdownload" value="427b0a45dd714d95bd11374b5a2d56b4" /></td>
<td>Equipment 001</td>
<td>Location A-1</td>
<td>Officer A</td></tr>
<tr class="even">
<td><input type="checkbox" name="chkdownload" 
value="76f888d5bb3740aabef70c5f50bea7d9" 
id="download_getSelectedFile_chkdownload"/><input type="hidden" 
id="__checkbox_download_getSelectedFile_chkdownload" 
name="__checkbox_chkdownload" value="76f888d5bb3740aabef70c5f50bea7d9" />
</td>
<td>Equipment 002</td>
<td>Location A-2</td>
<td >Officer S</td></tr>
</tbody></table>    
</div>

<!--for secretary users to view -->
<div class="usrSec usrAccess" style="display:none;">
<span class="pagebanner">2 records  found, displaying all pages.</span> 
<span class="pagelinks">Page 1</span>
<!-- put row2 to make the table id unique -->
<table id="row2" class="its">
<thead>
<tr>
<th><input type='checkbox' name='selectall' id='clickAll'/></th>
<th class="sortable">
<a href="equipment_view?d-16544-s=1&amp;d-16544-o=2&amp;d-16544-p=1">Equipment Name</a></th>
<th class="sortable">
<a href="equipment_view?d-16544-s=2&amp;d-16544-o=2&amp;d-16544-p=1">Location</a></th>
<th class="sortable sorted order2">
<a href="equipment_view?d-16544-s=3&amp;d-16544-o=2&amp;d-16544-p=1">Equipment Officer</a></th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="odd">
<td ><input type="checkbox" name="chkdownload" value="427b0a45dd714d95bd11374b5a2d56b4" id="download_getSelectedFile_chkdownload"/><input type="hidden" id="__checkbox_download_getSelectedFile_chkdownload" name="__checkbox_chkdownload" value="427b0a45dd714d95bd11374b5a2d56b4" /></td>
<td >Equipment 001</td>
<td >Location A-1</td>
<td >Officer A</td></tr>
<tr class="even">
<td ><input type="checkbox" name="chkdownload" value="76f888d5bb3740aabef70c5f50bea7d9" id="download_getSelectedFile_chkdownload"/><input type="hidden" id="__checkbox_download_getSelectedFile_chkdownload" name="__checkbox_chkdownload" value="76f888d5bb3740aabef70c5f50bea7d9" /></td>
<td >Equipment 002</td>
<td>Location A-2</td>
<td >Officer S</td></tr>
</tbody></table>    

</div>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Download Selected"/>    
 </form>
</div>
```

**Update 2**

For Secretary table, in jsp code, I put row2 for uid and in html source code I put row2 for id. I run the application, that table still cannot check all checkboxes whereas the other table works fine.

Although I have updated the code in the content, I extract the exact the code about the id part below for your quick review please. Thank you.

The code in jsp

```
<!--for administrator users to view -->
<display:table name="${equipmentList}" class="its" uid="row"
sort="list" pagesize="10" requestURI="equipment_view" export="false" defaultsort="1" defaultorder="descending">

 <!--for secretary users to view -->
<display:table name="${equipmentList}" class="its" uid="row2"
sort="list" pagesize="10" requestURI="equipment_view" export="false" defaultsort="1" defaultorder="descending">
```

The code in html source code

```
<!--for administrator  users to view -->
<table id="row" class="its">

 <!--for secretary users to view -->
 <table id="row2" class="its">
```

Comment: It seems you have a problem on client side. Replace the serverside code by html code what the browser receives.

Comment: @reporter, thanks for your comment. May I ask a question please? Do you mean I should change `<display:table><display:column></display:column></display:table>` to `<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>`?

Comment: Call your web application in your browser. Show the sourcecode there and paste the html source code from your both tables into your question. Then remove the jsp code in your post.

Comment: @reporter, thanks for your comment. I used Internet Explorer (IE) and followed your instruction. I run the application, I notice the result is still the same, only one type of user can check all checkboxes by one click whereas the other type of user cannot check all checkboxes. Does that mean I should focus on the unsuccessful part?

Comment: **We** want to see the html code, instead of jsp code!

Comment: @reporter, I have a quick glance for the html source code from the IE for both tables, they seem the same. I will read the code more carefully to find the difference.

Comment: @reporter, I have posted the html source code in the question, would you please feel free to have a look? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Yash Don't substitute tags.

Comment: @Learner Attribute `id` must be unique in page.

Comment: @AleksandrM, thanks for your comment. I put `uid="row2"` in the jsp code and `id="row2"` in html source code. When I run the program, the table still cannot check all checkboxes. Would you please feel free to see my latest update (**Update 2**) in the question and give some adivces? Thank you.

Comment: @Learner All id-s. Including `clickAll`.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution but it works.

Just copy the function use other name to define which table will use it. For example

```
 <display:columntitle="<input type='checkbox' name='selectall' id='clickAll_Admin'/>"><s:checkbox theme="simple" name="chkdownload_Admin" fieldValue='%{#attr.row.recordId}' /></display:column>


  <display:columntitle="<input type='checkbox' name='selectall' id='clickAll_Sec'/>"><s:checkbox theme="simple" name="chkdownload_Sec" fieldValue='%{#attr.row.recordId}' /></display:column>
```

Comment: Actually you don't need to copy function. Just unique id-s.